# How can I have parameters listed in a parameter page and refer them in a Unix shell script

Tags: shell, unix, parameters, parameter-passing

I have a Unix shell script where i have some oracle connectivity information to be passed to. My lead requested me to pass the parameters from a parameter page since the connectivity information can change from environment to environment. How can I do that in Unix. I have an existing script where it is using as below. But how will it be from a parameter sheet.

```
export ORACLE_SID=$1
#export ORACLE_HOME=/u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0.2.1210
host=$2
user=$3
pwd=$4
target_dir=$5
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its not clear what do you mean by parameter page....

$0, $1, $2 ... $9 are positional parameter and are passed via command-line arguments, where $0 refers to current script name, $1 is first argument passed and so on...  If your script is connect_db.sh then calling this script as **connect_db.sh ORCL dbhost scott tiger /tmp/reports** will set $1 to ORCL, $2 to dbhost, $3 to scott, $4 to tiger and $5 to /tmp/reports. See below demo script its output.

Three suggestion:

1. pwd is UNIX command so avoid using it as variable name
2. **set these variables in $HOME/.profile file of the user, so that these are set as soon as you login and script automatically picks these values from set environment variables and no need to pass them as positional parameters. And keep separate copy of .profile file for each environment**.
3. Avoid passing or storing password as cleartext

Demo Script

```
#!/bin/bash
# ScriptName: connect_db.sh 
# Date      : 2014-07-31
# Desc      : script for demo of positional parameter

echo "1st Parameter Passed is $1"
echo "2nd Parameter Passed is $2"
echo "3rd Parameter Passed is $3"
echo "4th Parameter Passed is $4"
echo "5th Parameter Passed is $5"

ORACLE_SID=$1
host=$2
user=$3
pass=$4
target_dir=$5

echo "----------------------------------------------"

echo "ORACLE_SID = $ORACLE_SID"
echo "host = $host"
echo "user = $user"
echo "pass = $pass"
echo "target_dir = $target_dir"

exit 0
```

Script Output

```
connect_db.sh ORCL localhost scott tiger /tmp/reports

1st Parameter Passed is ORCL
2nd Parameter Passed is localhost
3rd Parameter Passed is scott
4th Parameter Passed is tiger
5th Parameter Passed is /tmp/reports
----------------------------------------------
ORACLE_SID = ORCL
host = localhost
user = scott
pass = tiger
target_dir = /tmp/reports
```

Answer (score 0):

I worked out a way of doing this. I created a parameter file and have listed all my required parameters in the parameter file and then if the parameter file is created at the location `/filepath/parameter.sh` then I just made use of `. /filepath/parameter.sh` in my shell script and can just assign the values to my local parameters.

Please note that all the parameters in my parameter file have export in them, so:

```
export parameter1=100
export parameter2='/oracle/db/product/11.2.0.2'
```

etc.

Comment: Your thanks should be made as a comment to Narendra's answer.  Your own answer should be, and now is, a standalone explanation of what you've done.